# Accessing Office Graph apis with Sharepoint Online login?

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

We've been running an Angular app in a custom masterpage during the last year, using the Sharepoint REST api to retrieve user properties, data from lists etc., which has been working fine. As the application is hosted on Sharepoint Online, accessing the page requires a login thus making the request digest available so further authentication is not necessary.

Now however, we want to start using some of the functionality in the Microsoft Graph API. From what I can gather this requires OAuth2 authentication against the Azure Active Directory, involving among other things a redirect to the AAD login page.

Does this mean I have to:

1) Login via the organizations (standard Microsoft) login page to access the Sharepoint Online site.
2) Redirect to the Azure AD login page and back again?

Or can I leverage the login that the user already did when logging into Sharepoint Online?

Sorry if the question is a bit vague, we are all still very new to this.

Comment: Thanks for the answers below guys. Once I've continued to investigate I have clearer idea on what to do and how.

The page is protected by Sharepoint login which I cannot really get rid of. Once inside, the user is already authenticated, so all I have to do is retrieve the access_code & authorization_code via the normal OAuth2-process. The user is already authorized with his MS account so no need for a second login, but redirect is inevitable though.

As Benoit  & Eric said, I could use this authentication to access the Sharepoint lists but it is moot since I already am logged in to Sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When registering your application on Azure AD you will give the app access to Files/Sharepoint REST api and Microsoft Graph API. See [this picture](https://keluro.com/images/Blog/kmailteamAD.jpg) the app has access to several apis (Exchange, Graph and AD) you must add sharepoint APIs in your case.

Regarding the authentication, I am afraid that the Sharepoint model does not provide a token that will enable you to request the Graph API [see this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383.aspx#Perm_rightlist). You will have two authentications, one to access the Sharepoint site, as you said, and the other "within" the sharepoint iframed add-in to log into your AAD's registered app. This will be an OAUTH process through login.microsoft.com. Have a look at my Outlook add-in [Keluro Mail Team](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383.aspx#Perm_rightlist) on the Office store, I think it is similar to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same token from graph.microsoft.com. I have a sample using Asp.Net Core 1.0 and the.Net ADAL but the same authentication flow is used when using ASP.NET 4.6. Just make your auth request against ms graph on startup then acquire access token to auth against SharePoint.
https://github.com/edrohler/com.ericrohler

Hope this helps.